# Editing frames and encoding with MediaCodec

Tags: android, video, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I was able to decode an mp4 video. If I configure the decoder using a `Surface` I can see the video on screen. Now, I want to edit the frame (adding a yellow line or even better overlapping a tiny image) and encode the video as a new video. It is not necessary to show the video and I don't care now about the performance.(If I show the frames while editing I could have a gap if the editing function takes a lot of time), So, What do you recommend to me, configure the decoder with a GlSurface anyway and use `OpenGl` (GLES), or configure it with null and somehow convert the `Bytebuffer` to a `Bitmap`, modify it, and encode the bitmap as a byte array? Also I saw in Grafika page that you cand use a `Surface` with a custom Rederer and use `OpenGl` (GLES). Thanks

Comment: Hi! I am trying to implement something similar(using mediaprojection to get screenrecording only need to record user selected area). What I understood is I have to apply transformations to SurfaceTexture. But where should I create input surface for encoder. This input surface I need to supply to virtualdisplay where I get the frames. I followed grafika example to record screen. I am trying for a week now. Could you please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to use `OpenGLES`. ByteBuffer/Bitmap approach can not give realistic performance/features.

Now that you've been able to decode the Video (using MediaExtractor and Codec) to a `Surface`, you need to use the `SurfaceTexture` used to create the Surface as an `External Texture` and render using GLES to another `Surface` retrieved from `MediaCodec` configured as an encoder.

Though `Grafika` doesn't have an exactly similar complete project, you can start with your existing project and then try to use either of the following subprojects in grafika [Continuous Camera](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java) or [Show + capture camera](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java), which currently renders `Camera` frames (fed to SurfaceTexture) to a Video (and display).
So essentially, the only change is the `MediaCodec` feeding frames to `SurfaceTexture` instead of the `Camera`.

Google CTS [DecodeEditEncodeTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecodeEditEncodeTest.java) does exactly the same and can be used as a reference in order to make the learning curve smoother.

Using this approach, you can certainly do all sorts of things like manipulating the playback speed of video (fast forward and slow-down), adding all sorts of overlays on the scene, play with colors/pixels in the video using shaders etc.

Checkout *filters* in [Show + capture camera](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java) for an illustration for the same.

**Decode-edit-Encode flow**

When using OpenGLES, 'editing' of the frame happens via rendering using GLES to the Encoder's input surface.

If decoding and rendering+encoding are separated out in different threads, you're bound to skip a few frames every frame, unless you implement some sort of synchronisation between the two threads to keep the decoder waiting until the render+encode for that frame has happened on the other thread.

Although modern hardware codecs support simultaneous video encoding and decoding, I'd suggest, `do the decoding, rendering and encoding in the same thread`, especially in your case, when the performance is not a major concern right now. That will help avoiding the problems of having to handle synchronisation on your own and/or frame jumps.

Comment: Thanks!. I saw previously these examples and I think I should implement SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener, but I am afraid to lose some frames if my frame-Edit function would take a lot of time. As I asked, my idea is to implement like a batch process rather than showing what I am decoding-editing-encoding. I would like to edit after decoding and encoding in the same thread, rather than capturing the frames as If I would be recording from a camera.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I added a bit of detail on the decode-edit-encode flow.