# What is relation between MediaExtractor, MediaCodec and MediaMuxer in android SDK?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

I'm trying to make some deep learning experiments on android on video samples. And I've got stuck into remuxing videos. I have a couple of questions to arrange information in my head:) I have read some pages: https://vec.io/posts/android-hardware-decoding-with-mediacodec and https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest but still I have a mess.

My questions:

1. Can I read video with `MediaExtractor` and then pass data to `MediaMuxer` to save video in another file? Without using MediaCodec?
2. If I want to modify frames before saving, can I do that without using `Surface`? Just by modifying `ByteBuffer`? I assume that I need to decode data from `MediaExtractor`, then modify content, then encode it to `MediaMuxer`.
3. Does `sample` is the same as `frame` in context of method `MediaExtractor::readSampleData` ?
4. Do I need to decode sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a brief description of what each class does:

- MediaExtrator: Extracts encoded video/audio data
- MediaCodec: Depending on how its configured it can be a decoder or an encoder.
- MediaMuxer: Muxes streams of data into an output file.

This is how you pipeline should generally look like:

MediaExtractor -> MediaCodec(As Decoder) -> Your editing -> MediaCodec(As Encoder) -> MediaMuxer

To answer you questions:

1. MediaExtractor will give you encoded data, if you want to do
   anything with it you will have to decode it using a MediaCodec.
2. It might be possible to do so without a surface but it will be
   pretty limited. Surfaces is the way to go. You can find more info
   here:
   [Editing frames and encoding with MediaCodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932623/editing-frames-and-encoding-with-mediacodec)
3. Sample can be a video frame or an audio sample
4. Yes you do need to decode samples to edit them